# How do you store an array in core data (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

My code reads a text file and stores the contents of the file in an array. I'm having trouble with the next step; transferring the contents of the array into Core Data. The .txt file is just a short list of fruits. The entity is "Fruit" and the attribute is "fruitname".

Only the last array element is showing up when I print. Here's my code:-

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    // STORE .TXT FILE IN ARRAY.....
    let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
    let fruitList = bundle.pathForResource("List of Fruits", ofType: "txt")

    let fruitArray = String(contentsOfFile: fruitList!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!.componentsSeparatedByString("\r")


    for x in fruitArray {
        println(x)

    }

    // STORE FRUIT-ARRAY IN CORE DATA......
    var appDel = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate

    var context : NSManagedObjectContext! = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var newFruit = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Fruit", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

    for fruit in fruitArray {

        newFruit.setValue(fruit, forKey: "fruitname")
    }

    context.save(nil)


    // RETRIEVE AND PRINT STORED VALUES....
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Fruit")
    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    var results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error: nil)

    println(results)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

This is the output from both println statements....

// Println of fruitArray
Apple
Apricot
Banana
Bilberry
Blackberry
Blueberry
Coconut
Cranberry
Date
Dragonfruit
Fig
Grape
Guava
Honeydew
Kiwi
Lemon
Lime
Lychee
Mango
Melon
Orange
Papaya
Pineapple
Raspberry
Star fruit
Strawberry
Watermelon

//Println of core data

Optional(........ 
    fruitname = Watermelon;
})]

Can someone please help make sure that everything in fruitArray gets saved in core data? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have only created one `newFruit`.  Thus, your `for fruit in fruitArray` loop is just repeatedly reassigning the `fruitname` property.

Change your code to:

```
for fruit in fruitArray {
  var newFruit = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName ("Fruit", 
     inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObject

  newFruit.setValue(fruit, forKey: "fruitname")
}
```

Comment: Hence .insert-NEW-OBJECT-FOR-ENTITY-ForName. I should have caught that. Thanks for solving my problem, GoZoner. Wish I had more rep.